# One or two calls to API?

Tags: java, spring

I'm retrieving objects that are tagged with a hashtag from my database. A hashtag has a description associated with it. I want to be able to retrieve my objects from the database, but also retrieve the description associated with the hashtag. Should I be making two separate calls - one to get the objects, and one to get the hashtag description. Or should I be making one call where the objects and a description are returned?
Thanks.

Comment: My advice, return both.

Comment: Logically hashtag is related to the object, so if you make a call to the database to return the object then it makes sense to return all its associated properties (i.e. hashtag). Doesn't make sense to make a separate database call unless your design is totally different

Comment: look at hashtag on stackoverlow. The description will be loaded with extra call (on hover). So your service call should do ONE thing.

Answer (score 0):

> A hashtag has a description associated with it.

If the hash tag and the description form part of the same logical entity, then yes, it would make sense to have one call which returns both as some logical entity.

Doing two separate calls can do more harm than good since you would need to, at some point, process the data again to construct the said logical object, which, depending on what you have and how you do this step, can be time consuming and error prone. Also, what would happen if a user makes one call but not the second one? Would the data crash because you are missing a hash or a description?

Comment: The objects that I'm retrieving are a separate entity to the hashtag. The description is contained in the hashtag entity. I'm creating an app that uses hashtags in a similar way to Twitter. Clicking on a hashtag will bring up the associated tweets (or the "objects" I'm talking about in my post). As well as those objects, I need to get the description associated with the hashtag which will be displayed above those objects. The data wouldn't crash if I'm missing the description.

Comment: such things like hash description can be very well cached (on mobile device). No need to load them on every call.

Comment: @dit Yeah that's why I was thinking I should just make a separate call to get the description? Otherwise like you said, it'll be returned with every call.